# piping get-childitem into select-string in powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am sorting a large directory of files and I am trying to select individual lines from the output of an ls command and show those only, but I get weird results and I am not familiar enough with powershell to know what I'm doing wrong.

this approach works:

```
ls > data.txt
select-string 2012 data.txt
rm data.txt
```

but it seems wasteful to me to create a file just to read the data that I already have to fill into the file. I want to pipe the output directly to select-string.

I have tried this approach:

```
ls | select-string 2012
```

but that does not give me the appropriate output.

My *guess* is that I need to convert the output from ls into something select-string can work with, but I have no idea how to do that, or even whether that is actually the correct approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PowerShell is object-oriented, not pure text like `cmd`. If you want to get fileobjects(lines) that were modified in 2012, use:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq 2012 }
```

If you want to get fileobjects with "2012" in the filename, try:

```
Get-ChildItem *2012*
```

When you use

```
ls | select-string 2012
```

you're actually searching for lines with "2012" INSIDE every file that `ls` / `get-childitem` listed.

If you really need to use `select-string` on the output from `get-childitem`, try converting it to strings, then splitting up into lines and then search it. Like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem | Out-String) -split "`n" | Select-String 2012
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that covered basically everything I needed. I suspected from the start that powershell was doing something with objects but I couldn't figure out how to make it text.

Answer (score 4):

I found another simple way to convert objects to strings:

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-String -stream | Select-String 2012
```

in this very interesting article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/how-does-select-string-work-with-pipelines-of-objects.aspx

> > If you wanted Select-String to work on the Monad formatted output, you'll need to get that as a string.  Here is the thing to grok about
> >     our outputing.  When your command sequence emits a stream of strings,
> >     we emit it without processing.  If  instead, your command sequence
> >     emits a stream of objects, then we redirect those objects to the
> >     command Out-Default.  Out-Default looks at the type of the object and
> >     the registered formating metadata to see if there is a default view
> >     for that object type.  A view defines a FORMATTER and the metadata for
> >     that command.  Most objects get vectored to either Format-Table or
> >     Format-List (though they could go to Format-Wide or Format-Custom). 
> >     THESE FORMATTERS DO NOT EMIT STRINGS!  You can see this for yourself
> >     by the following: "These formating records are then vectored to an
> >     OUT-xxx command to be rendered into the appropriate data for a
> >     particular output device.  By default, they go to Out-Host but you can
> >     pipe this to Out-File, Out-Printer or Out-String.  (NOTE: these
> >     OUT-xxx commands are pretty clever, if you pipe formating objects to
> >     them, they'll render them.  If you pipe raw object to them, they'll
> >     first call the appropriate formatter and then render them.)